# Execute Cucumber Integration Tests with Spring Boot server running from Gradle plugin on Jenkins or any other CI server

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber-jvm, gradle-plugin, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a spring boot micro-services project built with Gradle.

I want to execute my cucumber integration tests on Jenkins or CI server just after code check-in. The build job on CI server gets triggered automatically after every code check-in. This job calls my **`gradle build`**.

I am able to execute the cucumber test cases as normal JUnit test case from my STS or eclipse and the embedded tomcat server gets started and after the cucumber test cases get executed on it, the server is stopped.

**This is exactly what I want through gradle build:**

**How the cucumber integration tests get executed on a running spring boot embedded server by gradle.build ??**

**Current behavior is**: when the **`gradle.build`** is called on CI server then the cucumber integration tests are just getting called with no target spring boot server.

**Expected behavior:** After **`gradle.build`** is called on CI server, the cucumber tests should get executed on the running spring boot embedded server and should get stop by itself after the cucumber test cases are executed.

**NOTE: I have created a special `cucumber-test` profile for it in the project and have its own configuration file**

My `gradle.build` looks like:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.pa.omas.Main'
    }
    baseName = 'omas'
    version = ''
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2" }
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task copyScripts(type: Copy) {
    from("scripts")
    into("build/libs")   
}

task copyReports(type: Copy) {
    from("reports")
    into("build/libs/reports")   
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test

tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}

bootRun { 
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=cucumber-test"] 
}

task cucumber(){
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava

    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['-p', 'pretty', '--monochrome', '-p', 'html:reports/cucumber/cucumber-html-reports', '-p', 'junit:reports/cucumber-junit/cucumber-junit-report.xml',
                    '-p', 'html:reports/cucumber', '--glue', 'src/integration-test/java/com/pa/omas/cucumber', 'src/integration-test/resources']
        }
        copyReports
    }
}

build {
   dependsOn copyScripts
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic')
    compile('org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.5.4')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8')
    compile 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:8.3'
    compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '3.11.0'
    compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'maven-cucumber-reporting', version: '3.11.0'

    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.6.3'
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310')
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.7.0'

    testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5'

    integrationTestCompile('com.h2database:h2')
    integrationTestCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    integrationTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5'
    integrationTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.5'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.5'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-html', version: '0.2.6'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.5'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.12.2'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'gherkin', version: '5.0.0'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '1.2.5'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'org.webjars.npm', name: 'gherkin', version: '4.1.3'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR3"
    }
}
```

My **`project structure`** looks like:

[image: Project Structure]

**`StepsDefinitionAnnotations`**

[image: StepsDefinitionAnnotations]

**`CucumberTest`**
[image: CucumberTest]

Thanks very much !!

Answer (score 1):

So finally, I found the solution to this issue.

The cucumber cli main class was unable to find the testRuntime in which the stepsDefinition file was located. Therefore, it was simply calling the cucumber test cases but not executing them.

All I did is included the ***sourceSets*** for main & test in the gradle file, linke below:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/test/"]
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked fine for me.

Thanks Anyways. Hope this will help others as well !!